# In classicthesis, is it possible to have lists of figures, listings etc. without leading "figure", "listing", etc?

Tags: tables, floats, formatting, lists, classicthesis

In `classicthesis`, how can I remove the leading "Figure", "Listing", or "Table" before the actual figure/listing/table number? In other words, what I have is:

```
Figure 1.1   An example of a quick floor plan sketch
Figure 1.2   Online floor plan design tool
```

What I want is:

```
1.1   An example of a quick floor plan sketch
1.2   Online floor plan design tool
```

Strangely enough, list of algorithms seems to already have this formatting applied:

[image]

Here is the code applied to create the lists in the above image:

```
\phantomsection
\manualmark%
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Listings}
\lstlistoflistings%

\vspace{4ex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Algorithms}
\listofalgorithms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{}
\settowidth{\figurelabelwidth}{999}
\cftsetindents{figure}{0em}{\figurelabelwidth}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{}
\settowidth{\tablelabelwidth}{999}
\cftsetindents{table}{0em}{\tablelabelwidth}
\renewcommand{\cftlistingspresnum}{}
\settowidth{\listingslabelwidth}{999}
\cftsetindents{listings}{0em}{\listingslabelwidth}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begingroup\let\clearpage\relax\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings
\endgroup

\mainmatter

\chapter{Test}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{A table caption}
\end{table}

\begin{lstlisting}[float=b,language=Pascal,frame=tb,caption={A floating example (\texttt{listings} manual)},label=lst:useless]
for i:=maxint downto 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{A table caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I used the tricks with `\clearpage` just to fit the three lists in a single page and make for a smaller set of pictures.

[image]

Please, do as Bringhurst says (`classicthesis` is based on his work): page numbers in lists are not to be summed up, so they don't need to be vertically aligned.

Comment: It works! Never thought of summed up pages, thx, good point!